# How do I correctly turn words from a file into a tuple or list

Tags: python

The program prints, but it prints what's in my files EXACTLY how they're written

```
import random

def getWords(filename):
    openFile = open(filename, 'r')
    readFile = openFile.read()
    listWords = []               
    listWords = [readFile]
    tupleList = tuple(listWords)
    return tupleList


nouns = "nouns.txt"
verbs = "verbs.txt"
prepo = "prepos.txt"
articles = "articles.txt"


prepositions = getWords(prepo)
nouns = getWords(nouns)
verbs = getWords(verbs)
articles = getWords(articles)

def sentence():
    return nounPhrase() + " " + verbPhrase()

def nounPhrase():
    return random.choice(articles) + " " + random.choice(nouns)

def verbPhrase():
    return random.choice(verbs) + " " + nounPhrase() + " " + \
        prepositionalPhrase()

def prepositionalPhrase():
    return random.choice(prepositions) + " " + nounPhrase()

def main():
    
    number = int(input("Enter the number of sentences: "))
    for count in range(number):
        print(sentence())

main()
```

I'm not entirely sure how to turn a set of words from a file into a tuple or a list for it to be later used as a random word choice.

An example output is:
a
an blake
billy
john run a
an blake
billy
john above
around
behind a
an blake
billy
john
a
an blake
billy
john run a
an blake
billy
john above
around
behind a
an blake
billy
john

Instead of the desired output being:
(only one of the words being input [chosen at random] going through to output)

blake run ahead
john run behind

(the coherence and grammar aren't problems in this case)

Comment: can you paste in an example from one of the files, for example the first few lines of `nouns.txt` so we know the input format?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: It depends on the file, some files only have a really short amount of words (minimum 1), nouns for example only has the word run, and a file like noun has: blake, john, billy. (for this one, the output keeps printing the commas)

Comment: If you specify the input you have, the output you want, and show your coding attempt (rather than auxiliary functions), we'll be able to help.

Comment: You could try `return readFile.split()` in your getWords function.

Answer (score 0):

What your getWords function needs is to after reading the file, split it up by the newlines. I'm assuming your file format is something like

```
noun1
noun2
noun3
etc
```

so your function should be something like this

```py
def getWords(filename):
    openFile = open(filename, 'r')
    readFile = openFile.read().split('\n')
    listWords = []               
    listWords = [readFile]
    tupleList = tuple(listWords)
    return tupleList
```

A suggestion to make the code cleaner:

```py
def getWords(filename):
    openFile = open(filename, 'r')
    return openFile.read().split('\n') # split() automatically returns a list
```